# zeroshell with multiwan on virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualization

I'm planning to setup Zeroshell as a router gateway for a school network on Virtualbox.

The host machine will run Ubuntu server edition. Then I will install Zeroshell as a guest Os with 4 configured lan adapters each of which are mapped to the physical ethernet cards on the machine.

The physical machine is connected to 3 WANs each of which are connected to the Internet. For each WAN, i will configure each virtual adapter as either bridge or nat depending on where they are connected. Bridged mode for the 2 wans which are connected to a modem/router with PPPOE and NAT for the last wan which is a leased line runnning on a /29 network.

The 4th ethernet adapter is connected to the Internal Lan of the school. This will be configured as bridged mode. This will be used by the Zeroshell guest OS as the default gateway for its DHCP configuration. Note that DHCP server of the LAN is running on Zeroshell that is on a virtual machine.

My question is, will this setup work and will it scale? What kind of problems I might encounter in the future? What is the minimum hardware requirements that I must use to get a decent performance out of this setup?

Comment: All other things aside, why run Zeroshell in a VM? Virtualbox isn't really meant from production use. I get you have three web connections but I'd reccomend some form of load balancer rather than a kludgey thing like this.

Comment: It might work. It might even scale. But it doesn't make any sense. Why virtualize the 'router'? Why use a consumer solution like virtualbox? Why not simply use an actual router?

Comment: Zeroshell does not have drivers for the 2 onboard lan adapters on the machine I am using. I could not think of any other way where I could use all the 4 Ethernet interfaces on the machine with Zeroshell.

Comment: Do you *have* to use Zeroshell?

Comment: We are using it now on our current setup. We are migrating to a new machine. Our zeroshell installation contains all the data used for user authentication. We need it for the captive portal, load balancing, free radius, firewall, qos and anti-virus proxy server it offers out of the box. 

i'm planning to test pfSense on the current machine but I can't do it at the moment. Do you have a recommendation for alternatives that we could use? thanks!

Comment: Use ESX Free if you have to use virtualisation, and not a consumer product...

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker unfortunately, we don't currently have the hardware to do that, everything went poof because of ActOfGod. We can't replace them at the moment, and I don't think they will be replaced any time soon. So we are using ordinary PC to serve as our router because it's cheaper for us.

Comment: @ultrajohn - if you build this you're going to be supporting it A LOT going forward, it looks borderline unsupportable to me/us sorry.

Comment: Take a look at vyatta (now closed source) / vyos (open source fork). It's based on Debian, has broad support for NICs and, from my experience, is rock solid. If you want to run a hypervisor then, as @Michelz says, try esxi, or even use KVM on ubuntu over virtualbox.

Comment: thanks everyone for your comments and suggestions. they helped me realized that I need to think a bit more on this one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pity you and your predicament of having to build this kludge :)

There are no reasons why any of this wouldn't work. It will probably even scale quite well if you give the VM enough resources. I would still advocate against the use of Virtualbox in favor of KVM, as I haven't had many decent results with virtualbox and have had quite a bit of good results with kvm, both with and without virt-manager.

I would also still try to get rid of the virtualization layer by compiling drivers from source, but that's not everybody's cup of tea.

Comment: I've checked and was going to try the "build-the-source-against-the-kernel" route but i can't seem to find the kernel source of zeroshell anywhere. thanks though!

Comment: or is it possible to compile the sources of the device drivers against an image of zeroshell (available from here http://www.zeroshell.org/download/) using a machine that runs a different flavor of linux e.g. ubuntu? Can I do that? 

I know this is off-topic, but I can't help myself. I am asking since you brought that up. :) thanks again!

Comment: Given that zeroshell uses open sourcee software, they must also distrubute the sources of their kernel. Using that, you can compile missing drivers.